# Vectorising while loop MATLAB insertion sort

Tags: matlab, sorting, for-loop, while-loop, insertion-sort

I need to use vectorization to remove the nested while loop inside my for loop, for making an insertion sort program. I am not allowed to have a while loop inside my for loop, I must do it "such that there are no while or for loops in your function except the outermost for loop."

Here is the code I have currently

```
 function insertsort(array)

 array = [2 1 3 2 1]

for i = 2:length(array)
    value = array(i);
    j = i - 1;

    while (j >= 1) && (array(j) > value)
       array(j+1) = array(j);
       j = j-1;
    end

   array(j+1) = value;

end %forLoop



 disp(array);
end %insertionSort
```

Answer (score 2):

This will do it:

```
array = [2 1 3 2 1]

for i = 2:length(array)
    value = array(i);
    j = i - 1;

    array_j=array(1:j);
    array_j_indices=cumsum(array_j>value);
    [~,n]=find(array_j_indices==1);
    newArray=array;
    array(n+1:i)=array_j(array_j>value);
    j=j-max(array_j_indices);
    array(j+1) = value;

end %forLoop

disp(array);
```

Explanation: First take elements from `j` to `1` in an array, since `while` loop will eventually scan through those elements. Find which of the elements are greater than the value and take its cumulative sum which will tell us how many elements are greater than the `value`. Because that is the amount we have to decrement `j` by. Now, find where the first `1` occurs (i.e. the first index at which the number is greater than `value`, since we have to shift every element to the right by 1 position from that index). After that, decrement `j` and put the value back. You are done.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you don't want to use the built in `sort` ?

```
ans=sort(array)
```

will do it.